# How nodes in cluster communicate in ElasticSearch and also how we decide in which node we should store document and later from where to retrieve?

Tags: java, search, indexing, elasticsearch

Being new to elastic search I have few questions on it.
1) How nodes in cluster communicate with Cluster in Elastic-Search?

2) How we decide in which node we should store document or how can we distribute our documents over different nodes?

3) Also at the time of searching where we should query means if data in on node 2 then can we query it from node 1 ?

I am using Java API for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you read this answer please refer the link to know about basic terms of [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html)

**Answer 1)**: Consider a single node is running.Now you add a new node with same cluster name. new the new node search for existing node with same cluster name. if it founds new node it ll cluster up together.Then load and data in first node is shared among those nodes.Elasticsearch use multicast to to find nodes.[**refer**](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html).

**Answer 2)**:We can distribute our documents over several nodes by using shards. shards split large no of docs into pieces and let them handle by different node.We cannot configure which data to store in which node. but we can configure to store a group of similar data in one shards using **[Routing](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html)**

**Answer 3)**:Yes, you can search for data in node2 from node1.Elasticsearch ll send your query to all shards of index and return the data.It internally send query to each node and fetch the result from all shards and perform **map-reduce**. The map-reduce result will returned to you.

HOpe it helps...